# I want to understand how Xamarin.UItest actually interacts with app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

So I am relatively new to Xamarin apps and Xamarin.UITest. What I want to understand is how it actually works under the hub? For example, for Appium we know that the script communicates with Appium server via JSONWP then Appium server sends response to UIAutomator which translates it and sends to Bootstrap.jar.

I know that communication is done through IApp Interface but I want to understand actually how it happens.